# Search Select not returning NotFound method

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I wrote a simple select to find searched data in a database. Thing is, in my case when there is no item in the database, method is returning an empty json.

```
[Route("api/Atributes/{value}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetAtributeByValue(string value)
{
    var atribute = ( from a in db.Atributes
                    join p in db.Cards on a.Atr_Nr equals p.Card_Nr
                    where a.Atr_Value == value
                    select new Employee
                    {
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Surname = p.Surname,
                        Number = a.Atr_Value
                    });

//this is statement id not working
    if (atribute == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(atribute);
}
```

Question is: Is this method of searching correct? If not how should I make it in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your result set to List and use its length property to check. LINQ has deferred execution. Fetch the actual result set with .ToList().

```
[Route("api/Atributes/{value}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetAtributeByValue(string value)
{
    var atribute = ( from a in db.Atributes
                    join p in db.Cards on a.Atr_Nr equals p.Card_Nr
                    where a.Atr_Value == value
                    select new Employee
                    {
                        Name = p.Name,
                        Surname = p.Surname,
                        Number = a.Atr_Value
                    }).ToList();

//use count, if that does not work, length here
    if (atribute.Count() == 0)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(atribute);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfect ;)

Comment: If you're using `ToList()` then it's useless to use `Count()` as it will iterate through the whole sequence. You should use `Count` property.

Comment: Does IEnumerable have count property? Also, he has to return data ultimately.

Comment: Your `atribute` variable is of type `List<>` since you've called `ToList()` which means you can call `Count` property instead of `Count()` Linq method.

Comment: Yes, i agree...I mentioned in comments there...//use count, if that does not work, length here...I just wrote the code in stackoverflow editor, did not type it in on computer. Count method can be used.

Comment: You could remove the ".ToList()" and change the "atribute.Count() == 0" to "!atribute.Any()"

Answer (score 0):

Seem like that the method is trying to a list of Atribute. So you just return atribute directly

```
[Route("api/Atributes/{value}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetAtributeByValue(string value)
{
var atribute = ( from a in db.Atributes
                join p in db.Cards on a.Atr_Nr equals p.Card_Nr
                where a.Atr_Value == value
                select new Employee
                {
                    Name = p.Name,
                    Surname = p.Surname,
                    Number = a.Atr_Value
                });

    return Ok(atribute);
}
```

EDIT:
Why not 404 (Not Found) ?

The 404 status code should be reserved for situations, in which a resource is not found. In this case, your resource is a collection of Atribute. This collection exists but it's currently empty. It is very confused as an author of a client for your application if I got a 200 one day and a 404 the next day just because someone happened to remove a couple of Atributes. What am I supposed to do? Is my URL wrong? Did someone change the API and neglect to leave a redirection.

Comment: Appears to me he wants to return a NotFound HTTP error code.